# $K_n \to K$ w.r.t Hausdorff metric and $K_n\subset K$. Is $K = \bigcup\limits_{n\geq 1}K_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, hausdorff-distance

Let $(X,\rho)$ be a compact metric space and $\mathcal{M}$ be the set of all compact subsets of $X$. Let $A\in \mathcal{M}$ and $(K_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{M}$ such that $K_n\subset A$ and $K_n\to A$ with respect to Hausdorff metric. Is it true that $A = \bigcup\limits_{n\geq 1}K_n$?

My thoughts:

$B:= \bigcup_{n\geq 1} K_n$. From the definition of the Hausdorff metric, $$d_H(C,D)= \max \{ \sup\limits_{c\in C} d(c,D), \ \sup\limits_{d\in D} d(d,C) \}$$
and since $K_n\subset A$, $B$ , for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we have that
$$d_H(A, K_n) = \sup\limits_{a\in A} d(a, K_n) = \sup\limits_{a\in A}  \inf\limits_{k\in K_n} d(a, k)$$
and
$$d_H(B, K_n) = \sup\limits_{b\in B} d(b, K_n) = \sup\limits_{b\in B}  \inf\limits_{k\in K_n} d(b, k)$$
By that and since $B\subset A$ we have that
$$d_H(B, K_n)\leq d_H(A, K_n)\underset{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$
Follows that $A=B$

Is this correct?

Comment: No, but it is true that $A=\overline{\bigcup_{n\ge1}K_n}$.

Comment: yeah. it was made clear to me after the answer was posted but  thank you anyways @Gae.S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true. Take $A=[0,1]$ and $K_n=[1/(2n), 1-1/(2n)]$, then $K_n$ converges to $A$ in the Hausdorff metric, but we have $A = [0,1] \neq (0,1) = \bigcup_{n\geq 1} K_n$.

In short, it fails as $B$ needs not to be compact.

Comment: thanks. that's what I was thinking but where does my reasoning break? .

Comment: As $B$ is not compact, we do not have $d_H(A,B)=0$ implies $A=B$.

Comment: so you are saying it should be $\overline{B}=A$. But then again, isn't it true 
 $\mathcal{M}$ endowed with the hausdorff metric is itself compact in this setting? then it should contain all the limit points and it seems $B$ is a limit point. It' not clear to me

Comment: Indeed, that is true, but $B$ is not compact and thus not even in $\mathcal{M}$. You add additional points and thus it is not compact anymore. In fact, $d_H$ is not even a metric on the power set of $X$ (exactly as there are sets that have zero Hausdorff distance, but are not equal).

Comment: I still don't get it though. Your counterexample is correct and on the other hand it should be (?) $B\in \mathcal{M}'\subset \mathcal{M}$.

Comment: It is correct and it needs to be. $B$ is not compact and thus not in $\mathcal{M}$. I do not know what $\mathcal{M}'$ is. I have to go to bed now, I'll answer to you tomorrow in case it is still unclear :)

Comment: Thanks anyways. By the way $\mathcal{M}$ is the set of all limit point of $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: It is not a limit point as it is not in $\mathcal{M}$ (as $B$ is not compact).

Comment: Consider the following metric space $X=\{a\}$ (which is compact). Now you introduce a "distance" $\rho$ on $\{ a,b \}$ with $\rho(x,y)=0$ for all $x,y\in \{a,b\}$. Now you say that $b\in X$ as it is a limit point as $\rho(a,b)=0$ and thus the sequence $(a)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ "converges" to $b$. The mistake is that a limit point must lie in the space in question from the start.

Comment: yeah. I think the problem lies on the fact that Hausdorff dinstance is not a metric on powerset. It seems like we need to  create some kind of equivalent classes, i.e. $A~B$ iff $A$, $B$ have the same closure and then we attain that the Hausdorff dinstance is a metric and this is why my reasoning fails.

Comment: That is exactly the reason :)